How to calculate this limit? $\lim_{x \to ±∞} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{x}!\bigg)x$
How is calculated this limit? $\lim_{x \to ±∞} \bigg(1-\frac{1}{x}!\bigg)x$
It presumably approaches γ, but I just don't know how.
I searched online and didn't see anyone finding γ by this limit. But maybe it's just another formula tweaked

The body of the Question should actually contain the question (not just the title).  Also, MathJax should be set off by "$"s.  Like "$\ln x$" becomes "$\ln x$".
